# Show the space of $(\alpha,\mu)$-Hölder continuous functions is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

CONTEXT: I want to show $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is not a linear subspace of $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

We call $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ an "$(\alpha,\mu)$-Hölder continuous function" if

$$
\exists_{\alpha,\mu>0} \forall_{x,y\in[0,1]}: |f(x)-f(y)|\leq\mu\cdot|x-y|^{\alpha}.
$$

Let $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ be the set of $(\alpha,\mu)$-Hölder continuous functions.

**I have previously shown that if $f\in F_{\alpha,\mu}$, then $p f\in F_{\alpha,|p|\mu}$, for all $p\in\mathbb{R}$. (1)**

I now want to show that $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is not closed under scalar multiplication. To do this, I assume it is closed under scalar multiplication. Proof by contradiction.

Suppose $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is closed under scalar multiplication for all $\alpha,\mu$. Let $f\in F_{\alpha,\mu}$. Then also $pf\in F_{\alpha,\mu}$ (because of closure). In the same way $\frac{1}{p}pf\in F_{\alpha,\mu}$, but because $pf\in F_{\alpha,\mu}$ we have by our previous result (1) that $f=\frac{1}{p}pf \in F_{\alpha,|\frac{1}{p}|\mu}$.

So we conclude that when $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is closed under scalar multiplication, we have that for all $f\in F{\alpha,\mu}$ that also $f\in F{\alpha,p\mu}$, for all $p\in\mathbb{R}$.

Returning to the definition I think this means that we now have

$$
\exists_{\alpha>0} \forall_{\mu\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}}\forall_{x,y\in[0,1]}:|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \mu\cdot|x-y|^{\alpha}.
$$

Because this is true for all $\mu$, also for $\mu$ approaching to zero, we have that $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$ and thus that $f$ is constant. **This is the line I cannot prove rigorously. I think it is true because $\alpha$ is fixed.**

We conclude that all Hölder continuous functions must be constant. But $f(x)=x$ is (1,1) Hölder continuous. Therefore $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ cannot be closed under scalar multiplication, **this was my false assumption**. So $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is not a linear subspace of $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

**Is this line of reasoning correct? And how do I fix the vagueness that I put in bold?**

Comment: I don't know that contradiction is necessary here. If $c\in\mathbb R$, then $|cf(x)-cf(y)|\leqslant c\mu|x-y|^\alpha$, and not $\leqslant \mu|cx-xy|^\alpha$ like you would need.

Comment: It is clear that if $f$ is $(\alpha,\mu)$-Hölder, then $|cf(x)-cf(y)|\leq |c|\mu |x-y|^{\alpha}$. Do you mean the contradiction does not work and the proof is senseless/false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument works to show that it is not true that $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is closed under scalar multiplication for all $\alpha$ and $\mu$.  For the step you asked about, there really isn't more you need to say: $|x-y|^\alpha$ is just some number $C$ and you know $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \mu C$ for all $\mu> 0$, which implies $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$.  To be very explicit, if $|f(x)-f(y)|$ were positive, you could take $\mu=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{2C}$ to get a contradiction (assuming $C\neq 0$, since the $C=0$ case is trivial).

Note though that this does not prove what you wanted to prove, which is that $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is not closed under scalar multiplication for *all* $\alpha$ and $\mu$.  All your argument shows is that there is some $\alpha$ and $\mu$ for which it is not closed under scalar multiplication.  To be more precise, what your argument really shows is that if $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ is closed under scalar multiplication for some particular $\alpha$ and $\mu$ then $F_{\alpha,\mu}$ consists only of constant functions.  So, your example $f(x)=x$ being in $F_{1,1}$ only shows that $F_{1,1}$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.  To show it in general, you need to consider arbitrary $\alpha$ and $\mu$ and find a nonconstant function in $F_{\alpha,\mu}$.

Comment: That makes sense. I had already tried working out other counter examples. So taking $f(x)=\mu x$ for example shows that $F_{1,\mu}$ is closed under scalar multiplication for any $\mu>0$. But since powers do not work distributively over subtraction, thus the (for me) obvious think to try was $f(x)=\mu x^{\alpha}$. Then you get $|f(x)-f(y)|=\mu|x^{\alpha} - y^{\alpha}| ?\leq? \mu|x-y|^{\alpha}$, which I think doesn't work

Comment: I found a proof that for $\alpha>1$, all Hölder continuous functions are constant functions, so for $\alpha>1$ the space of $\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions is indeed a linear subspace. I also figured that for $\alpha\leq 1$, the functions$f(x)=\mu x$ still works as a counter example. So my proof is complete (and the theorem partly falsified). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The point is that if $t$ is a real number such that $|t| \le \mu$ for all $\mu > 0$ then $t = 0$.  Well, this is rather obvious: if $t \ne 0$ you could take $\mu = |t|/2$...

Comment: Ah yes. That finishes the proof. But is the rest of reasoning correct? Can I indeed come to the conclusion that all Hölder continuous functions are constant, and does this then show that it cannot be closed under scalar multiplication? I'm not a very confident mathematician yet